# Gradle Sync Error: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

I'm using IntelliJ to synchronize Gradle. The Gradle project is provided by IntelliJ template, but still the error persists.

I've tried to:

1. Use Android Studio to do the same thing, same thing happened.
2. Reinstall IntelliJ, no use.
3. Clear the proxy settings, no use. I DID use VPN in the past, but not changing the proxy setting in the IntelliJ.

My system: MacOS Big Sur

So this is the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not download junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0)
Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.0/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar'.
Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.0/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar'.
The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
Remote host closed connection during handshake
SSL peer shut down incorrectly

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not download junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0)
Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.0/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar'.
Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.0/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar'.
The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
Remote host closed connection during handshake
SSL peer shut down incorrectly

at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:127)

...[omitted numerous lines]

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.0/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar'

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.0/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990)
```

This is my gradle build script:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

A ZILLION THANKS!!!!!!!!

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

This is because Maven Central and Bintray have announced that they will discontinue support for TLS v1.1 and below

replace mavenCentral() with maven { url = "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" } and jcenter() with maven { url = "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }

For more info: https://blog.gradle.org/unable-to-download-maven-central-bintray

Comment: Thank you! But how can you change the request protocol in IntelliJ? Like upgrading from TLS v1.1 to TLS v1.2?

Answer (score 3):

Try running the build task as  "gradle -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 clean build"
Incase you are using intellij to build add Vm arg "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to go about it thanks to [Katastros](https://blog.katastros.com/a?ID=01300-9639c4cf-ac75-4eb1-b1dc-1671a632d8ca)

Problem: New project sync gradle cannot be synchronized after installing Android Studio

Solution: modify the content under gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties,

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

To:

distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```